# Modulus of Reciprocal of Polynomial Bounded From Above When Exterior to Circle

Tags: complex-analysis

I am reading the book Complex Variables and Applications, (Brown and Churchill, 9th edition). I was reading the following example:

If n is a positive integer and if $a_0, a_1, a_2, . . . ,a_n$ are complex constants, where $a_n\neq 0$, the quantity
$P(z) = a_0 (a) + a_1 z + a_2 z^2 + · · · + a_n z^n$
is a polynomial of degree n. We shall show here that for some positive number R, the
reciprocal $1/P(z)$ satisfies the inequality
$$\left \lvert \frac{1}{P(z)}  \right \rvert<\frac{2}{|a_n|R^n} \qquad  \text{whenever }|z| > R$$

As part of the solution (attached below), they define:
$$ w= \frac{a_0}{z^n} +\frac{a_1}{z^{n-1}}+\frac{a_2}{z^{n-2}}+..+\frac{a_{n-1}}{z}$$
which leads to the inequality:
$$ (9) \qquad |w|\leq \frac{|a_0|}{|z|^n} +\frac{|a_1|}{|z|^{n-1}}+\frac{|a_2|}{|z|^{n-2}}+..+\frac{|a_{n-1}|}{|z|}$$

In regards to $(9)$, they say: "Now that a sufficiently large positive number R can be found such that each of the quotients on the right in inequality $(9)$ is less than the number $|a_n|/(2n)$ when $|z| > R$.

Why is this last statement true? How can I say what the relationship is between the quotients on the right of $(9)$ and the value of $|a_n|$?

[Excerpt from the book's solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Helf.png)

Comment: The question was answered with more details here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4242810/complex-proof-of-the-fundamental-theorem-of-algebra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$n$ and all the $a_i$ are fixed.

Since we want $$\frac {|a_i|}{|z|^{n-i}}<\frac {|a_n|}{2n}$$
for every $i$, a reasonable $R$ to pick is $$\max_i\sqrt[n-i]{2n\frac{|a_n|}{|a_i|}}$$

the quotients and $|a_n|$ need not be related.

Comment: Can you please explain how you arrived at this particular $R$?