# Complex proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, proof-explanation

I am self-studying Stein's Complex Analysis text, in which he has as proof for the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra. For some reason, something about it is just not clicking. Here is his proof itself (here $P$ is a non-constant polynomial):

> If $P$ has no roots, then $1/P(z)$ is a bounded holomorphic function. To see this, we can of course assume $a_n \neq 0$ and write
> $$\frac{P(z)}{z^n} = a_n + \Bigl(\frac{a_{n-1}}{z} + \cdots + \frac{a_0}{z^n} \Bigr)$$
> whenever $z \neq 0$. Since each term in the parentheses goes to 0 as $|z| \rightarrow \infty$ we conclude that there exists $R > 0$ so that if $c = |a_n|/2$, then
> $$|P(z)| \geq c|z|^n, \quad \text{whenever } |z| > R$$
> In particular, $P$ is bounded from below when $|z| > R$. Since $P$ is continuous and has no roots in the disc $|z| \leq R$, it is bounded from below in that disk as well, thereby proving our claim. By Liouville's theorem we then conclude that $1/P$ is constant. This contradicts our assumption that $P$ is non-constant and proves the corollary.

How does he conclude that there exists $R > 0 $ so that if $c = |a_n|/2$ then $|P(z)| \geq c|z|^n$ for $|z| > R$? Why is he choosing $c$ as he did? Also, how does he use this to deduce that $P$ is bounded from below?

Comment: For large enough $R$ you can get $|\Bigl(\frac{a_{n-1}}{z} + \cdots + \frac{a_0}{z^n} \Bigr) |\le \frac{|a_n|}{2}$ and then use the reverse triangle inequality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the expression for $P(z)/z^n$ it follows that
$$
\lim\limits_{z\to\infty}\frac{P(z)}{z^n}=a_n\neq 0
$$
Therefore, by definition of limit, by choosing $|z|$ large enough, say $|z|>R$ we can make $\left|\frac{P(z)}{z^n}\right|$ as close to $|a_n|$ as we want, say between $|a_n/2|$ and $|3a_n/2|$, so
$$
\left|\frac{P(z)}{z^n}\right|\ge c:=\frac{a_n}{2},\quad |z|>R
$$
and, consequently, $|P(z)|\ge cR^n$ if $|z|>R$, so $P$ is bounded below by the positive constant $cR^n$ outside of the ball of radius $R$. Inside, $|P|$ is clearly bounded below, being a positive continuous function on a compact set.

Comment: Thanks that clears things up. As well as proving boundedness from below, your proof also provides an explanation that $P$ is bounded from above by $|P(z)| \geq cR^n$, is that correct?

Comment: @CBBAM That is not correct. $P$ is never bounded from above. Any non constant polynomial grows at infinity (just look at the restriction over the reals, say). All you need is a bound from below, to be able to apply Liouville's theorem to $1/P$

Comment: I see, I was under the impression that a function had to be bounded both from above and from below to apply the theorem. So only one will suffice?

Comment: @CBBAM Boundedness "from above" and "from below" only makes sense for real functions, where you can say things like $m\le f(x)\le M$. We are talking about a complex function, which is bounded if $|f(z)|\le M$ (observe that this last inequality does not correspond to TWO different inequalities as in the real case). In your case, you know $|P|\ge C>0$ and therefore $|1/P|=1/|P|\le 1/C$. Your function $1/P$ is then bounded, and that is all you need to apply Liouville's Theorem.

Comment: Ah I see my error now, I guess I'm still carrying over my intuition from the reals to the complex numbers. My apologies, silly mistake on my part. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Write $P(z)=a_{n}z^{n}+...+a_{1}z+a_{0}$, $a_{n}$ different 0. idea is to compare P(z) with Q(z)=a_{n}z^{n} and use Rouché's Theorem. We have

$|P(z) -Q(z)|=|a_{n}z^{n}+...+a_{1}z+a_{0}-a_{n}z^{n}  |=|  a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+...+a_{1}z+a_{0} |$
and if z different $0$

$|Q(z)-P(z)/Q(z)|=|a_{n-1}/a_{n}+...+a_{1}/a_{n}z^{n-1}+a_{0}|$
Now
$\lim_{|z - \infty} |Q(z)-P(z)/Q(z)|=|a_{n-1}/a_{n}+...+a_{1}/a_{n}z^{n-1}+a_{0}|=0$
and therefore, we can find R>0 such that |z|>R then

$|Q(z)-P(z)/Q(z)|=|a_{n-1}/a_{n}+...+a_{1}/a_{n}z^{n-1}+a_{0}|<1$

Therefore, choosing any gamma circle with center at 0 and radius > R we have that, along gamma
$|Q(z)-P(z)|<|Q(z)|$
By Rouché's theorem P has precisely n zeros, counted with multiplicity

Comment: You seem to know MathJax (or LaTeX), but you need to put ```$``` around the math expressions to make it render in the math font.